# What adjustments would be necessary to have a remainder of 0 associated with Sunday?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calendar-computations

I was reading this below and I had a question:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131007/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html)

Take a look under "The Key Value Method" where it says "A remainder of 0 corresponds to Saturday, 1 means sunday, etc."

My Question:

It’s rough to start a week on Saturday. What adjustments would be necessary
to have a remainder of 0 associated with Sunday? (This might
allow a mnemonic of Nun-day, One-day, Twos-day, Wednesday, Fours-day,
Fives-day, Saturday.)

Comment: "Since this algorithm involves treating days of the week like numbers modulo 7, John Conway suggests thinking of the days of the week as "Noneday" or "Sansday" (for Sunday), "Oneday", "Twosday", "Treblesday", "Foursday", "Fiveday", and "Six-a-day"." From [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the original post, 0 is for Saturday, assume that it is an error on your part in writing.

Now to get 0 for Sunday, all you do is to subtract 1 (mod 7) to all the key values. So if Jan is 1, it becomes 0 and if Dec is 6 it becomes 5 and if Apr is 0 it becomes 6.  All other logic remains the same.